# Java Substring in if statement does not work

Tags: java, string, if-statement, substring

I'm trying to remove the last char in the string using `substring` method.
Outside the if statement works normally. But inside it just goes through the if statement and returns original `String`.

```
public String getElkon(int p, int zbytek) {   
    System.out.println(zbytek);

    for (int i = 0; i < p; i++) {
        vysledek += elkon[i];
        vysledek += " ";
        System.out.println(vysledek);
    }
  ***if(zbytek != 0){
        vysledek = vysledek.substring(0, vysledek.length() - 1);
        return vysledek;
    }
    else{
        return vysledek;
    }***

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code would be more straightforward if you didn't have to trim the trailing space from appending your `String`(s). Also, it isn't clear why you expect `zbytek` to control the `trim`. I think you wanted `if (p != 0)` (since that is your loop sentinel). I would use a [`StringJoiner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html) to implement this like

```
public String getElkon(int p, int zbytek) {
    System.out.println(zbytek);
    StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(" ");
    for (int i = 0; i < p; i++) {
        sj.append(elkon[i]);
    }
    return sj.toString();
}
```

Comment: A good thing to note here, is that 'StringJoiner' was created for ease of use with 'Stream's.  Though it will work just fine here, 'StringBuilder' will also work.

Answer (score 0):

The last character in the string is a space, since you added it last time in the `for` loop.

To trim the last space before `if` statement you could use the code

```
public String getElkon(int p, int zbytek) {   
    System.out.println(zbytek);

    for (int i = 0; i < p; i++) {
        vysledek += elkon[i];
        vysledek += " ";
        System.out.println(vysledek);
    }

    if (p > 0)
        vysledek = vysledek.substring(0, vysledek.length() - 1);

    if(zbytek != 0){    
       ...
    }

    return vysledek;     
}
```